# Artist or technician?

Tags: poll, artist, technician, sound-designer, designer

I find this question on some forum, so I am interested what do you think.

Is Sound designer artist or technician?

Some say it should be added Psychologist?

Answer (score 11):

It depends on the person, not the title

Comment: Wholeheartedly agree, and I'd argue that's why the field is so fascinating. Humans and sound are both far too complex to yield an easy this-or-that, right-or-wrong answer.

I might add that it sometimes even depends on your *role* on a project, even for the same person, since some gigs need more tech expertise and others need more raw creativity. 

Answer (score 8):

Definitely both. Creativity and technical ability are both essential characteristics in our field.

Answer (score 3):

I do believe that it is important to be both as having the technical aptitude in this day and age is important but creativity is essential to being a sound designer because you are painting a film with sound and it is important to be emotionally in touch with the film.

Answer (score 2):

A GOOD sound designer knows how to achieve their art via the technical process.  A sound designer without the technical knowledge to make it happen isn't much good to the project.

Answer (score 1):

An artist **is** an artist.

Yes, you may operate equipment, which is also what technicians do.

Yes, you may study or be influenced/inspired by human psychology, which is what psychologists do.

But to consider an artist a technician would be a bad analogy. To consider an artist a psychologist would be a false analogy. **Art is not about equipment, art is about human expression and/or the creation of beautiful or interesting things.** Nor is art genuinely (in a scientific way) about human psychology. Technology (and designing, operating and installing it) on the other hand is about equipment and getting useful things done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer that's better than Tim's, but to play devil's advocate - you can always hire people with better chops or ideas, but you can't get anyone else to have the relationship with the client for you.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day a good Sound Designer is what the client want him/her to be.  Never forget who pays the bills and always give the client what they want.  Technical whizz, creative genius or both!

Answer (score 0):

Both, it is up to the client how much of an artist they let you be, but you always have to be a technician.

Answer (score 0):

I've always been fond of the word 'craftsperson.' Implies a  mix of artistry and of technical proficiency.